# override primeng default style with scss file

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

I was trying to override one of the default style on the primeng card but some reason when I use the scss file, style is not applied. Below is the code I tried and same code works on the css file.

I have below code on template

```
        <p-card>
            <app-component></app-component>
        </p-card>
```

and tried this on scss file

```
:host >>> .p-card .p-card-body {
    padding:  0.5rem;
}
```

and I have this on appComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Same style works when I used the css but not working on scss file. Is there any thing else I have to do for it?

Comment: Can you also share the template(html) code of the component?

Comment: Did you replace `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` by `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']`?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

you can custom most of primeng components style by set a class as parent class for the component with *styleClass* after that you can overrate component element classes

template

```html
<p-card styleClass="ngx-color">
  <app-component></app-component>
</p-card>
```

example
style.scss

```css
.ngx-color {
  &.p-card {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .p-card-title {
  }
  .p-card-body {
    padding: 2rem !important;
    background: #a6120d;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-card-demo-uzfp5g?file=src/styles.scss)

check this [primeng theming](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/theming)

> each component have different set of class you check these class at style section of official component documentation page as example [card](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/card).

Comment: Thank you for your comment but some reason I moved the same style code to app.component.scss style file and it is not working. I have rename your app.component.css with scss and also added the template Url on ts file. Just to make sure I have added the another div and changed the color that is working but card style is not. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-card-demo-bxddn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Comment: if you move the style to component style file you need to set `encapsulation` to `none` https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-card-demo-aispka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I think it is not required if use host. Here I am doing without setting  encapsulation 
 to none but css file. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-card-demo-c8ywzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css. Looking for same but on scss file

Comment: if you don't use custom class then you don't need to set encapsulation to none

Comment: I will not recommend this way `host >>> .p-card .p-card-body {}` because it not reusable but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep .p-card .p-card-body {
    padding:  0.5rem;
  }
}
```

Just copy and paste this in your scss file.

Comment: this is one way to do it but angular is slowly deprecating ::ng-deep selector

Comment: ::ng-deep should be avoided because it'll be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I found the solution, first thing set `ViewEncapsulation` to none of ts file, and just add `.p-card.p-component .p-card-body { ......./ }`